# How to translate Kafka pub-sub semantics into a peakNext promise semantics for unittesting in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

While unittesting my NodeJS application I'm trying to create a simple helper class that will translate the Kafka pub-sub semantics into a simpler API suited for unittesting.

My idea is to be able to write mocha unittest like this:

```
        const testSubscriber = kafkaTestHelper.getTestSubscriber({topic:'test'});
        return someKafkaProducer.sendAsync({topic: 'test', message: randomWord})
          .then(() =>
            testSubscriber.next()
          ).then(msg => {
            msg.should.equal(randomWord);
          });
```

Of course I would also add helper methods such as

```
testSubscriber.nextUntil(someFilter)
```

This is inspired by the AKKA.NET TestKit which has a similar approach.

I have two questions:

1. Is this a reasonable approach or is there some cleaner way to unittest application logic based on Kafka stream processing in NodeJS?
2. Can anybody post coding examples showing how to make testSubscriber work as I intend?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant solution but it seems to work, at least for my initial testing. The trick is to create an ever growing list of Promises for which the resolver function is kept by reference in an array called 'resolvers'. Then when a message comes in, the resolver is invoked with the message. In this way I can return promises to any unittest invoking next() and it will work transparently if either the message was already delivered or it will be delivered in the future.

I still feel I'm reinventing the wheel here, so any comments would still be greatly appreciated.

```
    function TestSubscriber(consumer, initialMessageFilter) {
      this.consumer = consumer;
      let promiseBuffer = [];
      let resolvers = [];
      let resolveCounter = 0;
      let isStarted = false;
      const ensurePromiseBuffer = function() {
        if (promiseBuffer.length === 0 || resolveCounter >= resolvers.length) {
          const newPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolvers.push(resolve);
          });
          promiseBuffer.push(newPromise);
        }
      }
      const that = this;
      this.consumer.on('message', function(message) {
        if (!isStarted) {
          //Determine if we should start now.
          isStarted = initialMessageFilter === undefined || initialMessageFilter(message);
        }
        if (isStarted) {
          ensurePromiseBuffer();
          const resolver = resolvers[resolveCounter];
          resolver(message);
          resolveCounter++;
          that.consumer.commit(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              //Just log any errors here as we are running inside a unittest
              log.warn(err)
            }
          })
        }
      });
      this.next = function() {
        ensurePromiseBuffer();
        return promiseBuffer.shift();
      };
    }

    const cache = {};

    module.exports = {
      getTestSubscriber: function({topic}, initialMessageFilter) {
        if (!cache[topic]) {
          const consumer = kafka.getConsumer({topic, groupId: GROUP_ID});
          cache[topic] = new TestSubscriber(consumer, initialMessageFilter);
        }
        return cache[topic];
      }
    }
```